# Multiple Vagrant Boxes MySQL connection error

Tags: mysql, vagrant, mariadb, vagrantfile

I'm a newbie with Vagrant and it seems I fail to make this work. I've successfully created 2 Vagrant boxes with Ubuntu 14.04 and everything seems to work fine but the MySQL (MariaDB to be exact).

I can connect to the DB through ssh but when I use a tool like HeidiSQL if I connect to the first DB I fail to connect to the second one or I connect to the first one instead :/

It seems like the localhost/127.0.0.1 mess things up.

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "first.test"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vm_provision/provision-ubuntu-14.04.sh"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.1"
  config.vm.synced_folder "db/", "/var/lib/mysql/", disabled: false

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name = "VagrantTest1"
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "50", "--cpus", "1"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end
end
```

The 2nd box got a different hostname, IP and box name.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

PS: I am trying to make 2 different boxes where 1st one will hold 5 websites that are under the same server and 2nd one 3 smaller ones which are on a small VPS.

Comment: Are they in separate Vagrantfiles?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes they are

Comment: Can you SSH to both?  Do `vagrant ssh-config` for both and examine the output.

Comment: @AlJacinto yes I can. It seems like HeidiSQL messes up these two. No idea why though.